# Spring Injection in maven-plugin's @Mojo

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, maven-plugin

I'm trying to use Spring DI in a custom maven plugin I'm creating.

When using the plugin however, I get the following error:

```
Unable to load the mojo 'cva2sch' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'dge:preparation-maven-plugin:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1) null returned by binding at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
```

Although I have an @Configuration (with @ComponentScan) class and @Component on the @Mojo class, I guess the maven-plugin doesn't use Spring.
Is it impossible to use Spring DI in a @Mojo at all, or is there some special setup required to do so?